# How to multiply columns in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following three column data (first row is header) in a csv format

| Value | Y | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 8 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 5 |
| C | 7 | 9 |

I want the following output also in a csv format

| Value | Y*X |
| --- | --- |
| AB | 40 |
| BA | 6 |
| AC | 72 |
| CA | 14 |
| BC | 27 |
| CB | 35 |

Is there a way to accomplish this in bash?
thank you

Here is the csv file copy-paste

```
VALUE,Y,X
A,13,7
C,0,0
D,3,25
E,2,44
F,0,6
H,1,1
I,5,3
K,45,3
L,1,31
M,2,3
N,3,3
P,113,87
Q,13,11
R,20,5
S,7,9
T,9,4
V,7,3
Y,1,0
```

I tried `awk '{print $2*$3}' TEST.dat` but the problem is it is not combinatorial i.e. not multiplying every column 2 value to every column 3 value.

Comment: You need to create a transpose, from there create a 2D-matrix, containing the multiplications, and then you need to turn this back into a 1D-matrix. This is not that easy in Excel, but doing this in bash??? And most important, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide actual CSV data that can be copy and pasted into a test file.

Comment: _in Bash_ Just use awk.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by turn this back into a 1D-matrix. I can transpose to get a 2D matrix in excel easily. But then how do I go ahead with them multiplication. I am a novice and tried my hand at writing a python script but the problem is I have to manuall input the value of A, B and C. I have files with hundreds of rows so this is not really practical.

Comment: Post some trial, please. Don't post it as as an image or comment but edit it to your original post. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. There is a RFC (4081 if I remember well) that somehow standardizes the CSV format but many supposedly CSV files do not follow this. And there is a high probability that yours is no exception. So, please copy-paste the textual content of your file in your question. We should see something like `"A",8,2`...

Comment: I am a novice so please bear with me. I tried awk '{print $2*$3}' TEST.dat but the problem is it is not combinatorial i.e. not multiplying every column 2 value to every column 3 value.

Comment: Wonderful! What you have is a real CSV file. Just tell `awk` that the field separator is a comma (`awk -F',' ...`) and you're done.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Thanks. I tried but again it is only multiplying column 2 and 3 in a single row. I want the value in column 2 and row 2 to be multiplied with every row of column 3. Additionally, it should also output the corresponding text values in column 1.

Comment: @Jalan Oh, I see. I there a specific expected order of your output?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, its always Y*X and never the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, 'BEGIN { print "VALUE,Y*X"; i=0 } # Print header
         FNR == 1 { next } # Skip existing header lines
         FNR == NR { x[++i]=$3; values[i]=$1; next } # First pass through the file
         { # Second pass; multiply current row against every saved row
           for (n = 1; n <= i; n++) 
             if (values[n] != $1) # Except itself
               printf "%s%s,%d\n", $1, values[n], $2 * x[n]
         }' input.csv input.csv
```

Process the file twice; first time saving the x values, and second time multiplying the current line's y against all the saved x's.

---

For fun, a version that uses sqlite, importing the CSV file and then doing a self-join:

```sh
sqlite3 -batch -header -csv <<EOF
.import input.csv data
SELECT a.value || b.value AS "VALUE", a.y * b.x AS "Y*X"
FROM data AS a
JOIN data AS b ON a.value <> b.value
ORDER BY a.rowid, b.rowid;
EOF
```

---

And pure bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a values yvalues xvalues
exec 3<input.csv
read -r -u 3 _ # Read and discard header
declare -i i=0
while IFS=, read -r -u 3 value y x; do
    i+=1
    values[i]=$value
    yvalues[i]=$y
    xvalues[i]=$x
done

echo "VALUE,Y*X"
for ((a=1; a<=i; a++)); do
    for ((b=1; b<=i; b++)); do
        if [[ $a -ne $b ]]; then
            printf "%s%s,%d\n" "${values[a]}" "${values[b]}" \
                   "$(( yvalues[a] * xvalues[b] ))"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Super. That worked like a charm. I was wondering if you would so kind to perhaps explain the syntax a bit. The line containining printf is not clear to me. Also why the two input.csv?

Comment: @Jalan Two input.csv's to read the file twice.

Comment: (You could do it in `awk` with one pass; it'd end up using nested loops in an `END` block, similar to the approach the pure `bash` version I added later uses. I just think it's cleaner this way.)

Comment: the pure bash solution is amazing. Given that I have multiple files to process, something like this is more feasible. Thank you  :)